# How do I determine the error propagation of my table?

Tags: python, prediction, error-propagation

I have different predictions for the future (table below). These two predictions `V1` and `V2` are both telling us something about the future and therefore have to be multiplied to find the total sum of the future predictions.

```
V1                         V2                         Vtotal
31 ± 17 %                  59 ± 41 %                  108 ± ?? %
18 ± 17 %                  24 ± 26 %                  46 ± ?? %
```

For additional information, Vtotal is calculated based on: 1.31 x 1.59 = 2.08 = 2.08 - 1 = 1.08.
How can you then address the standard error for `Vtotal` based on the standard error of the two predicted variables `V1` and `V2`?

Comment: Are V1 and V2 independent?

Comment: @cdalitz yes they are.

Answer (score 0):

As you say that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are independent, you can use Gauss' law of error propagation:

$$\sigma^2(V_{total}) = \sum_i \left(\frac{\partial V_{total}}{\partial V_i}\right)^2 \sigma^2(V_i)$$

where the partial derivatives are evaluated at the mean values for $V_1$ and $V_2$.